# Dojo: How to test if a JMS topic exists?

Tags: javascript, java, dojo, jms, jms-topic

I have Dojo code that looks like this:

```
topic.subscribe('path/to/some/topic');
```

How do I test whether I subscribed to a JMS topic that actually exists? I have a suspicion that there's nothing on the other-side of `path/to/some/topic` but I'm having trouble figuring out how I do that.

I need a Dojo specific answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I verify that a JMS queue exists using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260342/how-do-i-verify-that-a-jms-queue-exists-using-java)

Comment: @notyou not a dojo specific answer. I would like to test from dojo if possible

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback function to see if you have subscribed to a specific topic, for example:

```
topic.subscribe( 'path/to/some/topic', function() {
    console.log( "I have subscribed successfully." );
} );
```

However, as a side note, you need to make sure that there is `topic.publish( 'path/to/some/topic' );` in order to trigger the callback function in topic.subscribe.